# Why the MAX14830 does not transmit?

Tags: i2c, uart, bridge

I am using a MAX14830 as an I2C-UART bridge. My problem is that it does not trans it after I write data to the transmit (THR) register.

My initialization procedure is as follows:

1. Reset the chip (set but RST from MODE2 register);
2. Clear RST bit;
3. Clear FIFOs (set FIFORst from MODE2 register);
4. Clear FIFORst from MODE2 register;
5. Clear interrupts (by reading the ISR register).

Afterwards I write data (bytes) to the THR register, but it does not transmit anything on any of the 4 UARTs. Instead, the TX FIFO level is always increasing (TxFIFOLvl). Also, I confirm the transmitter is enabled (the TxDisabl bit from MODE1 register is cleared), the clock signal is OK (I measured it using an oscilloscope after configuring the chip to output it on one of the GPIOs) and I2C communication works fine.

Does anybody know what is the problem? Can it be a faulty chip? Any suggestions on how to further debug this issue?

Comment: External comms inputs might not be set correctly. Does it have any external hardware handshake lines that need to be set correctly?

Comment: @Andyaka Hi. I do not use the RTS and CTS lines. Also, I checked the flow control register (FlowCtrl) and its value is 0, so no AutoRTS or AutoCTS is used. It is very strange that the FIFO buffer always keeps increasing on all the UARTs, when it should be decreasing since the chip should automatically transmit any byte found in the buffer. It suggests this may be a software issue (or a faulty chip).

Comment: Do you have your clock set up correctly? Need an XIN input and some setup of baud rate, PLL, etc. If that's not there then it makes sense your FIFO level increases: you keep adding bytes to the FIFO but they are not being emptied.

Comment: So, what have you got electrically connected to RTS and CTS. Having nothing connected isn't an option despite what you say.

Comment: @td127 I confirm the clock is set up correctly. I verified it by outputting it on one of the chip's GPIOs and measuring it using an oscilloscope. I also checked the clock signal on the crystal's pins and it is OK.

Comment: @Andyaka I understand your point of view. You can have a look at my schematics: https://ibb.co/RDCmPp8 and https://ibb.co/w6ZGssr . They are designed by following the schematics from the MAX14830 datasheet.

Comment: @Andyaka A minor remark: the crystal used is 3.6864MHz, not 16MHz as shown in the schematics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was an incorrect setting. I mistakenly set the ClkDisabl bit high and that disabled communication. Now I have the problem that the data is transmitted in 7-bit format, not in the standard 8-bit format. But this is a different issue.